# Custom text wrap in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that accepts string and a number that represents width of each line that is to be created.

**Here is how it accepts input:**
WrapText(string,20);

What this function should do is to put maximum of "width" characters (in this example 20) of string on every line.

**Before wrap:**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum.

**After wrap:**

Lorem ipsum dolor

sit amet,

consectetuer

adipiscing elit.

Curabitur vitae diam

non enim vestibulum

interdum.

---

Maximum of 20 characters are in line and the line must fit whole words, not cut them in middle.

**Can somebody help me with an algorithm for this? I tried some stuff but I just can't get it right.**

Something I tried:

```
int x=0,line=0,total=0;
while(arr[x]!='\0'){
    if(arr[x]!=' '){
        line++;
    }else{
        if(total+line>=width){
            arr[x]='\n';
        }else{
            line++;
            total+=line;
        }
        line=0;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: *I tried some stuff* - show us this stuff and explain why it is not working.

Comment: I can recommend the K&R book. Take your time, it is worth it if you really want to learn C. This exercise is one of the exercises in the book actually. it will teach you anything you need.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added code I made, it works for first line but then it just breaks and puts 1 word on every line.

Comment: Time to learn how to debug; this is the single most important skill a coder will ever learn. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are not resetting your counters.  So, once your first line is created, you need to reset `total`, and `line` back to zero.  But, also note that this one change will print out lines that are longer than 20 chars.

Comment: Look forwards until you have 20 characters. Look backwards until you have a space. Replace space with `'\n'` character. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan ahead, reading each word and computing its length before you output anything. You can do this by copying the word into a temporary buffer, or you can use pointers to do it as you scan.

Using a buffer is simple, but since you don't know how large a buffer to allocate it has inherent limitations.

The pointer version can be done as a simple state machine with two states, BETWEEN_WORDS and IN_WORD. All the interesting stuff happens only at state transitions; scanning words or whitespace is just read-ahead.

Pseudocode:

```
initial state = BETWEEN_WORDS
start_of_word_ptr = null

for each character,
    if whitespace, then
        if the current state is IN_WORD, then
            the new state is BETWEEN_WORDS
            word_length = current_pos - start_of_word_pos
            if current_line_length + word_length + 1 > max_line_length, then
                /* start a new line */
                print linefeed
                current_line_length = 0
            else
                /* output space */
                print a space between words
                current_line_length++
    else if not whitespace, then
        if the current state is BETWEEN_WORDS, then
            the new state is IN_WORD
            start_of_word_ptr = current_ptr

        /* output word */
        print the characters from start_of_word_pos to current_pos
        current_line_length += word_length
```

That is a basic algorithm that will do what you want for a string input. Customize to taste.